# Play audio in template. Django

Tags: python, django, audio

There is a problem with playing audio in my project. I have a `worder.html` where is an information about a word and its pronunciation. The problem is that the PLAY button is not active and I can't listen the pronunciation.

This is how it looks in template:

```
<h2>{{ showword.title }}</h2>

    <audio controls preload="auto">
    <source src="{{ showword.audio }}" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>

    <p class="translation"> Русский: {{ showword.russian|safe }}</p>
<p class="translation"> English: {{ showword.english|safe }}</p>
<p class="translation"> Türkçe: {{ showword.turkish|safe }}</p>
```

The audio files upload by admin, the users aren't allowed to upload them.

This is how my model looks like:

```
class word(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to='Dictionary/media', blank=True)
    russian = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    english = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    turkish = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
```

This is my MEDIA settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/PycharmProjects/Test/Dictionary/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to a file in templates using the [`url` attribute of `FileField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url):

```
<source src="{{ showword.audio.url }}" type="audio/mpeg">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but now I have another problem. If there's no uploaded audio file for a post it shows **ValueError at /worder/8/
The 'audio' attribute has no file associated with it.**

Comment: You can hide the widget if no audio file is available. Just surround the code with `{% if showword.audio %}<audio>...</audio>{% endif %}`

Comment: so now I have the same problem but in deployment... I set `DEBUG = False` and now pronunciation doesn't sound.. What should I change in my code?

Comment: Could be an issue with static/media files paths but you should consider asking a new question.